# Ionic 2 ion-card getElementById returns null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ion-card list of elements in a page and I want to navigate to a specific position when entering the view, the page renders properly and I can see in the generated code that div with specific id is indeed on the view but trying to get the element by id is returning null.

Here is the code for the view where I build the cards:

```
<ion-content class="cards-bg">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let meal of meals">
      <ion-card-header>
        {{meal.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'}}
      </ion-card-header>
      <div id="{{meal.id}}">
        <img src="{{serverUrl + '/' + meal.picture}}">
      </div>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{meal.title}}
      </ion-card-title>
      <p>{{meal.description}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-row no-padding></ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

And this is the code that tries to get the reference to the element so I can navigate to it:

```
public index: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams, public mealService: MealService) {
     this.index = navParams.get('index');
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.mealService.getMeals().then((result) => {
      this.meals = result;
      let yOffset = document.getElementById(this.index).offsetTop;
      this.content.scrollTo(0, yOffset, 1000);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

As I mentioned the page with cards render, I can even see the generated code contains the specific div with id but the call:

```
document.getElementById(this.index)
```

returns null, so I get the following error in logs:

> chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(57687)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (57687)

Comment: Are you finding the id of this <div id="{{meal.id}}">?
then remove the "", use this <div id={{meal.id}}>

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular`s [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

Inject it in constructor:

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef){}
```

For getting the element,

```
let el = this.elRef.nativeElement;//get underlying native element.
let yOffset = el.getElementById(this.index).offsetTop;
```

Or you could also use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html):

Set an id for the div:

```
  <div #divElement id="{{meal.id}}">
    <img src="{{serverUrl + '/' + meal.picture}}">
  </div>
```

Set the decorator on a class variable:

```
@ViewChildren('divElement')
divs:any;
```

For accessing elements,

```
let yOffset = this.divs[this.index].nativeElement.offsetTop
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested first option and looks like it doesn't work with ionic 2 - I get the error: TypeError: el.getElementById is not a function. Will try the second one now. Used import : import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

Comment: Second option gives error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
I will keep trying and keep you posted. 
Debugging I can see that this.divs is returning an empty array.